# Spark mllib svd gives: Java OutOfMemory Error

Tags: apache-spark

I am using the svd library of mllib to do some dimensionality reduction on a big matrix:

- the data is about 20G,
- and the spark memory is 60G

I got the following warning and error message:

> WARN ARPACK: Failed to load implementation from:
>   com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeSystemARPACK  WARN ARPACK: Failed to
>   load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeRefARPACK 
>   WARN BLAS: Failed to load implementation from:
>   com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeSystemBLAS  WARN BLAS: Failed to load
>   implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeRefBLAS  Exception
>   in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
>
> ```
> at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:2766) 
> at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.EigenValueDecomposition$.symmetricEigs(EigenValueDecomposition.scala:128)
>
> at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix.computeSVD(RowMatrix.scala:258)
>
> at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix.computeSVD(RowMatrix.scala:190)
> ```

To resolve the warning messages, I build **Spark (1.2)** with the command
`-Pnetlib-lgpl` locally, and the warning messages disappeared when I test locally. And the log shows the netlib library is working properly:

> 15/03/05 20:07:03 INFO JniLoader: successfully loaded
>   /tmp/jniloader7217840327264308862netlib-native_system-linux-x86_64.so 
>   15/03/05 20:07:11 INFO JniLoader: already loaded
>   netlib-native_system-linux-x86_64.so

Then I installed the **Spark (1.2)** compiled with `-Pnetlib-lgpl on AWS EMR`, but the warning and error message still shows up.

I was not sure whether it is the problem of my local compilation, so I compiled `Spark (1.2) on AWS EC2` and installed it on AWS EMR, but the warning and error message still shows up.

Could anyone tell me how to solve this problem? Much appreciated!

Comment: Did you perform the profile compilation on all nodes in the cluster, or just the master node?

Comment: What do you mean by "Spark memory is 60G" -- you are running a non distributed operation so only driver memory matters

Comment: @DanOsipov I only performed the compilation on the master node. Should I perform the profile compilation on all nodes in the cluster, and how can I do that?

Comment: @SeanOwen I am running distributed operation on 10 machine with 6G memory on each. I did not specify the driver and worker memories. Should I set this?

Comment: The SVD operation you are calling happens on the driver. The covariance matrix is calculated on the cluster though. Where are you running out of memory? Driver right?

Comment: Hi @SeanOwen, I think the error happens while java is copying an array. So I think this happens on the driver. How should I fix this? Use a larger driver memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is partially solved. Thanks for the comments by @SeanOwen.

The reason why I am getting the java memory error is because, the computation for top eigenvectors are on the driver, so I need to make sure that I have enough memory on the driver node.

When using `spark-submit` with `--driver-memory 5G`, the problem is solved.

But the warning messages still exist.

Comment: Warning is intentional in case when columns are greater than 10k. See `line 137` at SVD [source code on github](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/distributed/RowMatrix.scala)